# Два двоеточия в предложении: допустимо или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Предложение такое:

> Космос я тоже видел таким, каким его можно увидеть только в безвоздушном пространстве: полное отсутствие светотеней, все очень контрастное: черное и белое.

Может ли быть два двоеточия в предложении и насколько это грамотно? Или в данном случае перед "черное и белое" нужно было поставить тире?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В таких предложениях второе двоеточие предлагается заменять тире вопреки правилу. Двоеточие показывает границу между частями сложного предложения, тире выделит уточняющее "черное и белое". Так предложение лучше воспринимается читающими. Такая замена подается как возможная. См. [Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=488)

Comment: Не только возможная, но и желательная, т.к. тире в конце предложения отделяет однородные члены со значением пояснения

Comment: А насчёт допустимости - допустимы и два двоеточия, если они объяснимы правилами.В официальном стиле особенно, там важна точность и логика содержательной части. Но  данное предложение не относится к официальному стилю, там возможна замена на тире, почему бы не воспользоваться ей и не убрать громоздкую пунктуацию?

Answer (score 4):

Взгляните на [вопрос 177700](http://83.222.3.68/spravka/buro/?page=5638)

"Скажите, пожалуйста, может ли быть два двоеточия в предложении? Федеральный Конституционный суд признал лишь одно исключение из данного правила: принцип приоритета европейского права не применяется, если речь идет об основных структурных принципах Конституции, а именно: принципах федерализма, демократии и уважения неотъемлемых прав и свобод личности. 
Мария

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Употребление двух двоеточий в одном предложении корректно."

Answer (score 4):

Если несколько частей сложного предложения **последовательно связаны значениями причины, пояснения** (возможна подстановка союзов *потому что, а именно*), то, вопреки общему правилу (и в том и в другом случае правила предусматривают постановку двоеточия), **возможна замена одного из двоеточий знаком тире для передачи разных оттенков значения.**
[§161. Взаимодействие знаков препинания в сложных конструкциях](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

В вашем предложении два двоеточия предусмотрены правилами — можно оставить как есть. Но для лучшего восприятия конструкции с "пояснением пояснения" лучше поставить тире.

**Космос я тоже видел таким, каким его можно увидеть только в безвоздушном пространстве: полное отсутствие светотеней, все очень контрастное — черное и белое.**

Нашлось похожее предложение.
*А вот и почтальон. Она хорошо знала его автомобиль: небольшой, приземистый, раскрашенный в яркие тона — красный, белый и синий.*
[Джон Болл. Пять осколков нефрита](https://www.rulit.me/books/pyat-oskolkov-nefrita-read-305503-1.html)

Answer (score 3):

Допустимо, но нежелательно.

> [Вопрос № 281694](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=281694)
>   Правильно ли стоят двоеточия, если нет, то почему: "Скачу я и думаю: может, и в самом деле врежут в спину, да только нет, не будут: зачем же им лошадь портить?"
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Такая пунктуация возможна, но два двоеточия в одном предложении нежелательны. Предложение лучше разбить на два.