Почему использовать несколько двоеточий в одном предложении нежелательно?
Листал вопросы и ответы по теме использования двух и более двоеточий, но не нашёл ни одного вразумительного пояснения следующему: почему считается, что их употребление в одном предложении «нежелательно»? Аж на тире предлагают заменить, что кажется совершенно необоснованной рекомендацией.
P.S. попросили пример. Прикладываю:

Мне открылась картина довольно грустная: широкая сакля, крыша которой
опиралась на два закопчённых столба, была полна скорбящего народа: и
Андрей, и Фёкла, и Фёдор, и девушки — все собрались, чтобы почтить
память Ивана: сегодня уже десять лет, как он погиб, защищая дом от
захватчиков.


Тут такое дело. Поставить можно и три двоеточия, но как этот прочитать и как объяснить грамматику? Приводите конкретные примеры, тогда можно разговаривать.  Предложение с двумя двоеточиями нужно по Лопатину рассматривать как сложное синтаксическое целое, делить на блоки т. д.

Повтор вопроса, ответ принят
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17210/Два-двоеточия-в-предложении-допустимо-или-нет/445249#445249

@Арчи Похоже, что представленное предложение — это подражание Лермонтову. Тут открылась картина довольно занимательная: широкая сакля, которой крыша опиралась на два закопченные столба, была полна народа. Посередине трещал огонек, разложенный на земле, и дым, выталкиваемый обратно ветром из отверстия в крыше, расстилался вокруг такой густой пеленою, что я долго не мог осмотреться; у  огня сидели две старухи, множество детей и один худощавый грузин, все в лохмотьях ( «Герой нашего времени»).

Точно, подражание! Вот умора! Откуда у вас это предложение, риторика странная  (сначала сакля, потом дом)) Дальше можно по Пушкину продолжить? Получается,что мы до бесконечности можем  продолжать такую грамматику с помощью двоеточия.  Например, третья часть с пояснительным значением: именно в этот день они получили то письмо с фронта.  Поэтому предлагаю использовать точку, как у Лермонтова или уж точку с запятой.

ВРАЗУМИТЕЛЬНОЕ ОБЪЯСНЕНИЕ
Использование в одном предложении двух двоеточий нежелательно? Я бы сказала даже — запретно!
Это необоснованное деление сложного предложения на три части, но разве оно состоит из трех частей? Нет!
Как правило, сложное синтаксическое целое неоднородно по структуре и состоит из двух частей. Об этом говорится в правилах Лопатина, таково прочтение предложения в устной речи. Соответственно, все внимание направлено на один знак, и  часто это именно двоеточие.
В предложении по возможности не должно быть одинаковых знаков — это закон! Но откуда же тогда берется беззаконие? Это тоже объяснимо. Достаточно увидеть в сложном предложении не цельную структуру, а нечто бесформенное, состоящее из отдельных частей. Тогда мы к каждой части применяем правило о постановке двоеточия, но разве это разумно?
Все в такой пунктуации нехорошо, даже графика. Но главное — такая постановка знаков не позволяет правильно выявить структуру предложения и понять его содержание.
РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ
Космос я тоже видел таким, каким его можно увидеть только в безвоздушном пространстве: полное отсутствие светотеней, все очень контрастное — черное и белое.
В предложении четыре предикативные основы и два блока. Основная связь между блоками обозначена двоеточием. В последнем предложении пояснительные отношения обозначены тире, что допускается правилами.
Только такое решение следует считать правильным, а иначе основная связь между блоками будет неясно обозначена.
Пример из литературы:
Где находится тот гроб, Принц не ведал… или притворялся, что не ведает: как понял Ройд, особого стремления оживать и жениться на спасительнице у Принца не было – участь бессмертного, нестареющего духа его вполне устраивала.
По правилам в обоих случаях должна стоять двоеточие, но второе двоеточие заменили тире.
О сложных синтаксических конструкциях
Два двоеточия в предложении: допустимо или нет?

Спасибо за правку.  Рада видеть вас на форуме)   I really need an editor, honestly)
